# Retrieve existing Wallet objects on Android

Tags: android, android-pay

I have Android app that provides "Save to Android Pay" functionality for our customer loyalty card.
Seems to be working pretty good with the exception of one thing. I am unable to prevent duplicate loyalty cards being stored in Android Pay. It seems that there is no way to enumerate existing Wallet objects without initiating some sort of transaction. 
Is it possible with current Wallet API for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you use the same ID when creating the button, only one item is "saved" into user's google account even when user clicks button multiple times (though user can save a single card into multiple accounts if she choose to so).

If you're requirement is to "hide" button once it's saved, you have to query Google's server and see if loyaltycard for particular ID is already saved.
https://developers.google.com/save-to-android-pay/reference/v1/loyaltyobject/get